# Row Number Tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following Syntax

```
 select rcp.CalendarPeriodId
       ,rc.CalendarId
       ,rcp.CalendarYearId
       ,rcp.PeriodNumber
       ,rcp.PeriodStartDate,rcp.PeriodEndDate
       ,CASE WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN rcp.PeriodStartDate AND rcp.PeriodEndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'CurrentPeriod'
from RentCalendarPeriod rcp
LEFT JOIN RentCalendarYear rcy ON rcy.CalenderYearId = rcp.CalendarYearId
LEFT JOIN RentCalendar rc ON rc.CalendarId = rcy.CalendarId
```

What this is doing is that a I have two Calendars (CalenderID 1 = Weekly, CalenderID 2 = Monthly) This is the RentCalendar table.

Each Rent Calendar has a Year (RentCalendarYear table),which in turn each Year has a set of periods.

[image]

You will notice that line 47, the final column has been marked as 1 (true) This is because it is the current period.

What I need to do is mark the previous 12 periods for any CalendarId. I was wondering if I could achieve this with ROW_NUMBER, with the field CurrentPeriod WHERE = 1 will be 1 and all periods before will start to be numbered 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on.

I don't know how to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

So something like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM (
 select rcp.CalendarPeriodId,rc.CalendarId,rcp.CalendarYearId,rcp.PeriodNumber,rcp.PeriodStartDate,rcp.PeriodEndDate,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PeriodStartDate DESC) AS CurrentPeriod
from RentCalendarPeriod rcp
LEFT JOIN RentCalendarYear rcy ON rcy.CalenderYearId = rcp.CalendarYearId
LEFT JOIN RentCalendar rc ON rc.CalendarId = rcy.CalendarId)
WHERE currentperiod <= 12
```

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.. this will give you for the latests week 1, second one 2 , third one 3 and so on in CurrentPeriod column

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT rcp.CalendarPeriodId, rc.CalendarId, rcp.CalendarYearId, 
          rcp.PeriodNumber, rcp.PeriodStartDate, rcp.PeriodEndDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rcp.CalendarPeriodId) AS rn,
          CASE 
             WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN rcp.PeriodStartDate AND 
                                    rcp.PeriodEndDate THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
          END AS 'CurrentPeriod'
   FROM RentCalendarPeriod rcp
   LEFT JOIN RentCalendarYear rcy ON rcy.CalenderYearId = rcp.CalendarYearId
   LEFT JOIN RentCalendar rc ON rc.CalendarId = rcy.CalendarId
)
SELECT CalendarPeriodId, CalendarId, CalendarYearId,
       PeriodNumber, PeriodStartDate, PeriodEndDate,
       'CurrentPeriod',
       (t.rn + 1) - c.rn AS rn
FROM CTE AS c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT rn FROM CTE WHERE 'CurrentPeriod' = 1) AS t
WHERE rn BETWEEN t.rn - 11 AND t.rn
```

This will return 12 records, the one having `CurrentPeriod = 1` and the *previous* 11 records. Field `rn` enumerates records starting from the one having `CurrentPeriod = 1`.

Comment: I get the following error -Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Ambiguous column name 'rn'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Ambiguous column name 'rn'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Ambiguous column name 'rn'.

Comment: @ikilledbill Please check the edit I made. You should first try fixing this bug by yourself though.